# How to match all .sass request to a particular controller in pylons?

Tags: python, routes, pylons, sass

I'm using pylons, and want to use clever css.

I created a controller `SassController` to handle `.sass` requests, but in the `config/routing.py`, I don't know how to write the mapping.

What I want is:

1. client request: http://localhost:5000/stylesheets/questions/index.sass
2. all such requests will be handled by `SassController#index`

I tried:

```
map.connect('/{path:.*}.sass', controller='sass', action='index')
```

But found only: `http://localhost:5000/xxx.sass` will be handled, but `http://localhost:5000/xxx/yyy.sass` won't.

What should I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The routing code using regular expressions so you can make it eat everything in the url regardless of slashes.

The docs are [here](http://routes.groovie.org/setting_up.html)

It'll look something like:

```
map.connect(R'/{path:.*?}.sass', controller='SassController', action='index') 

#in the SassController
def index(self, path):
    return path
```

`http://localhost:5000/blah/blah/something.sass` will call `SassController.index` with `path = blah/blah/something`

Comment: Have you tried this? I remember(but not sure) I have done the same thing, but if the sass files in "public/stylesheets" directory, and you request "/stylesheets/xxx.sass", this route won't be used, I still get the raw sass content. I have to move the sass files to another directory and it works.

Comment: Yep, I tried this using the example I posted. I tried it with Pylons 1.0.